# How do I create repository using GitHub API in Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

My Retrofit query:

```
@POST("/user/repos")
@Headers("Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json")
suspend fun testCreateRepo(
    @Header("Authorization") accessToken: String,
    @Body repo: Repository
): Response<Repo>
```

Repository class (actually I have more params, but I left only necessary one to simplify example):

```
data class Repository(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String
)
```

Call:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val res = RetrofitBuilder.apiGitHub.testCreateRepo(token,
        Repository("test")
    )
}
```

What I get as response is **422 Unprocessable Entity**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason of this response. I was trying to create repository with name already taken by another repository of mine. Data class is fine.